# Why doesn't `-` (minus) work for operator sections?

Tags: haskell

Based on the position, the partial applications in Haskell gets the correct answer.

```
Prelude> (/2) 10
5.0
Prelude> (2/) 10
0.2
Prelude> (+3) 10
13
Prelude> (3+) 10
13
```

However, for - operator, I got an error with `(-3)` as Haskell (seems to) interprets it as a value `-3` not partial application.

```
Prelude> (-3) 10

<interactive>:4:1:
    Could not deduce (Num (a0 -> t))
      arising from the ambiguity check for ‘it’
    from the context (Num (a -> t), Num a)
      bound by the inferred type for ‘it’: (Num (a -> t), Num a) => t
      at <interactive>:4:1-7
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    When checking that ‘it’
      has the inferred type ‘forall a t. (Num (a -> t), Num a) => t’
    Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

How to solve this issue to get `7` in this example?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`subtract`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:subtract). `-` is the only operator in Haskell, that occurs both in a prefix *and* binary infix variant:

```
let a = -3     -- prefix  variant
let b = (-3)   -- also prefix variant!
let c = 4 - 3  -- binary variant
```

Therefore, you would have to use `(subtract 3) 10`. See also [section 3.4 in the Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-280003.4) (emphasis mine):

> The special form `-e` denotes prefix negation, the **only prefix operator in Haskell**, and is syntax for `negate (e)`. The binary `-` operator does not necessarily refer to the definition of `-` in the Prelude; it may be rebound by the module system. However, unary `-` will always refer to the `negate` function defined in the Prelude. There is no link between the local meaning of the `-` operator and unary negation.
>
> Prefix negation has the same precedence as the infix operator `-` defined in the Prelude (see Table 4.1 ). Because `e1-e2` parses as an infix application of the binary operator `-`, one must write `e1(-e2)` for the alternative parsing. Similarly, `(-)` is syntax for `(\ x y -> x-y)`, as with any infix operator, and does not denote `(\ x -> -x)`— one must use `negate` for that.

And [section 3.5](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5) concludes (again, emphasis mine):

> Because `-` is treated specially in the grammar, `(- exp)` is not a section, but an application of prefix negation, as described in the preceding section. However, **there is a `subtract` function defined in the Prelude** such that `(subtract exp)` is equivalent to the disallowed section. The expression `(+ (- exp))` can serve the same purpose.